# Creación Trigger - Problema con Update

Tags: mysql, mysqli, trigger, update, crud

Tengo una base de datos: **envia_trigger** que es idéntica a una base de datos: **recibe_trigger** y quiero que cuando **envia_trigger** se le haga un CRUD esta se actualice automáticamente a la **recibe_trigger**. Para eso creé un TRIGGER cuando hace insección y borrado
Aquí parte del código de la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE `account` (
    `id_test` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `acct_num` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `amount` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_test`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=14
;
```

Acá los trigger que funcionan perfectamente:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `account_INSERT`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `account_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `account` 
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO recibe_trigger.account VALUES(NEW.id_test, NEW.acct_num, NEW.amount);

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `account_DELETE`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `account_DELETE` BEFORE DELETE ON `account` 
FOR EACH ROW DELETE FROM `recibe_trigger`.`account` WHERE OLD.`id_test` LIMIT 1
```

Pero el problema está en UPDATE:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `account_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `account` 
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE `recibe_trigger`.`account` 
SET acct_num = NEW.acct_num WHERE `account`.`id_test`= NEW.`id_test`
```

Se debe conocer qué columna fue modificacada para así referenciarlo correctamente en el TRIGGER, por ejemplo: En el código del update arriba si se modifica dentro de la columna **envia_trigger.account** cambia perfectamente en la tabla **recibe_trigger.account** pero si se cambia en **envia_trigger.amount** no cambia (porque no está referenciado). ¿Cómo se puede hacer esta referencia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que solo estabas actualizando un campo en el trigger-update
debes de actualizar todos, además en el where debes de usar el OLD, por si cambian el id_test

```
CREATE TRIGGER `account_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `account` 
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE `recibe_trigger`.`account`
SET acct_num = NEW.acct_num,amount = NEW.amount,id_test = NEW.id_test  WHERE id_test = OLD.id_test
```